# Multiple headless browsers in Windows environment?

Tags: python, node.js, automation, pyqt, pyside

Is there a way to use multiple headless browsers (simultaneously) in Windows to do web automation testing?

Preferably I need to automate a browser with full javascript support so a modern Qt backend, with webkit implemented, would be ideal.

[Spynner](https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner) and [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) looked promising but only support an X11 environment for "more than 1 browser" setups.

Any ideas?

Comment: No idea, out of curiosity, is there something you're using that does a *single* headless browser on windows?

Comment: Mechanize for multiple headless in Python, but no JS support. Selenium for non-headless. But one VM per running test doesn't scale very easily.

Comment: It that headless? Haven't done win32 + selenium in a couple years, but at the time it was fully visible. And... well... a bunch of VMs is kind of the easy approach :P. Clouds imo.

Comment: The Requests library also works "headlessly" in parallel for REST API testing...but now I'm trying to automate the last frontier :)

Comment: @ViktorKerkez in my testing it couldn't run more than one browser instance at a time in Windows, making the headless feature moot.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez sample on pastebin? Did you do any special setup?

Comment: Unless you can provide an example I'm inclined to believe it didn't work correctly; there's a lot more to mass automation than starting 10 instances with a url serially.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about starting ten instances of PhantomJS?

Comment: For me, every time I've tried, when you start multiple instances of any "solution" that uses Qt as the backend things will crash when you try and get attributes from them. My theory is Qt is using a shared instance of webkit and doesn't have the capability to have independent processes of a webkit instance.

Comment: Would an [X Server for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453/what-is-a-good-and-free-x-server-for-windows) work with Spynner or Ghost.py?

Comment: Neat. MobaXTerm looks promising....I didn't have much success with cygwin.

Comment: Headless as in using no GUI or no screen?

Comment: No gui....filler chars

Comment: "Unless you can provide an example I'm inclined to believe it didn't work correctly" Can you provide a simple example of that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @blakev Would you please review my answer before the bounty runs out? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last year I was able to get this to work in both languages...

I used `zombie` for node and `Ghost.py` for python.

The Qt webkit backend now supports "tabs" in their Browser objects that allows for multiple sandboxed browsers to run simultaneously. I believe there was also an enhancement that broke a shared instance between a single webkit model not allowing more than one to be instantiated at a time.

On node I've had upwards of 60 independent browsers at once that rotate using an object pool, and in Python I've only ever needed 20-30; but it worked flawlessly as well.

Comment: Can you share more details/script?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node It says *"You can also make multiple phantomjs processes by calling phantom.create() multiple times, so if you need that for some crazy reason, knock yourself out!"*

Additionally https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/Uj5SV6o214w/chFBUnw3vxQJ says also something about running multiple "Page requests" on one Phantom.js thread. Also http://daker.me/2013/07/testing-your-responsive-design-with-phantomjs.html shows a way to implement this with the Async library.

I got it working with the following code:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var async = require('async');

var pagesToCall = [
    ['http://www.google.com', 8000],
    ['http://www.allthingsd.com', 8001],
    ['http://www.wired.com', 8002],
    ['http://www.mashable.com', 8003],
    ['http://www.stackoverflow.com', 8004]
];

function callPage(pageToCall) {

    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ': Started page ' + pageToCall[0]);
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ': port:' + pageToCall[1]);

    phantom.create({port: pageToCall[1]}, function(ph) {

        ph.createPage(function(page) {

            page.open(pageToCall[0], function(status) {

                console.log(new Date().getTime() + ': Opened page? %s', status);

                page.set('viewportSize', {
                    width: 1280,
                    height: 800
                });
                page.set('settings.userAgent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1');

                var filename = pageToCall[0].replace('http:\/\/', '') + '.png';
                page.render('./screenshots/' + filename, function() {

                    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ': Wrote page ' + pageToCall[0]);
                    page.close();
                    ph.exit();

                });

            });

        });

    });

}

//Main
async.each(pagesToCall, callPage, function (e) {
    if (e) console.log(e);
});
```

This is a quick hack. I'm sure this can be implemented much nicer with little more time. The pagesToCall array takes two arguments: The URL of the Website to be called, and a port number for the communication socket with PhantomJS.

The NodeJS modules I used are:

- https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node
- https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: I'm aware it says you "can" do it...but, it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Actually, it does work for me on Windows 7: Please see https://gist.github.com/tobilg/6493767 for the code!

Comment: Awarded for most effort -- I'll have to look into this a little more later. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

What about http://dalekjs.com/ 
It looks promising.